# HTML details tag with further text opens

Tags: html

I know that how details works, something like this:

```
<details>Hello World<summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another<summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
```

Actually it makes a details button in the next line.

But I wanted something that opens further text continuing the sentence.
Like:

```
I am fine and [More details]
```

If I click on [More details] then it opens and completes the full sentence with `"what about you?"` How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1) Using jQuery**

```
Visit below link for `Read More` example.
```

[Jquery Load More example](https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA)

**Solution 2) Using HTML and CSS only**

```css
body {
  font: 14px verdana;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3.6em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 200px;
}

#show_more {
  display: none;
}

#show_more:checked + .content {
  height: auto;
}
.show_more_btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
.show_more_btn:after {
  content: "Show More";
}
#show_more:checked + .content + .show_more_btn:after {
  content: "Less";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="show_more" type="checkbox">
  <div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <label for="show_more" class="show_more_btn"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any possibilities with only html ?

Comment: I update my answer and added HTML only solution as well. Now accept my answer.

Comment: @Ali You aren't changing the content of the button.

Comment: @ShakhawatHossain Buddy you can't event change that :(, zzz.

Comment: @ShakhawatHossain check code snippet now read more text changing now

Comment: @Ali Nice way of copying someone else's answer.

Comment: Ah okayy. Thanks . .

Answer (score 0):

Simple toggle content version with just HTML and CSS. The `:checked` attribute of `input[type=checkbox]` is the systematic toggle between showing/hiding the content.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span {
  visibility: visible;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

label:before {
  content: 'More';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label:before {
  content: 'Less';
}
```

```html
<p>I am fine and <input type="checkbox" id="show-more"> <span>how are you?</span><label for="show-more"> details</label></p>
```